# Compare 2 string in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, if-statement, string-comparison

I'm trying yo read some specific data from an XML by the use of a IF sentence, it doesn't seem to work though. My code:

```
tipo=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("tipo")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
subcategoria=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("subcategoria")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    if (tipo=="comer" && subcategoria=="bodegas") {
        Bodegas.push(x[i].getElementsByTagName("nombre")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue)

    };
```

I've been debuging via alerts, and I can tell that tipo & subcategoria values are "comer" and "bodegas" for sure, but when I put an alert inside the if sentence it doesn't run, so I guess the comparison is not properly done. Any ideas?  Thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried alerting `(tipo == "comer" ? "YES" : "NO")` and `(subcategoria == "bodegas" ? "YES" : "NO")` to see if it's both of the variables that are going wrong?

Comment: I've just tried, both statements return NO, wtf

Comment: You can share your code on JsFiddler ?

Comment: Are you sure that the actual string isn't `comer*[SPACE]*` or `*[SPACE]*comer` etc? There isn't any spaces or something? Try to use `alert("'" + tipo + "'");` and see if there's anything between the `'` that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Okey,that was the problem, the xml file was filled with white spaces, thank you so much man.

Answer (score 2):

On comparing Strings always call the `trim()` and `toLowerCase()` on both sides of the query to ensure there are no casing or spaces issues.